# AngularJs: Test service with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I did this controller

```
  app.controller('controller',['$scope','httpServices',function($scope,httpServices){
    $scope.items= undefined;

    httpServices.getItems( function(items){
        $scope.items= items;
    });
}]);
```

and I wrote this test

```
 describe('controller', function () {
        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller('controller', {
                '$scope': scope
            });
        }));
        it('defined', function () {
            expect(scope.items).toBeUndefined();
        })
    });
```

How I can test the scope.items after to have called the service?

Comment: Any reason you're not returning a promise from `httpServices.getItems` ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your service `httpServices` is making some http requests. Therefore you should use the [`mock-backend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) service in order to test your controller.

Something like this, pay attention to the comments that I've made inside the code:

```
describe('Your specs', function() {
  var $scope,
      $controller,
      $httpBackend;

  // Load the services's module
  beforeEach(module('yourApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope, _$httpBackend_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $controller = _$controller_;

    //THIS LINE IS VERY IMPORTANT, HERE YOU HAVE TO MOCK THE RESPONSE FROM THE BACKEND 
    $httpBackend.when('GET', 'http://WHATEVER.COM/API/SOMETHING/').respond({});

    var createController = function(){
      $controller('controller', {$scope: $scope});
    }
  }));

  describe('Your controller', function() {  
    it('items should be undefined', function() {
      createController();
      expect(scope.items).toBeUndefined();
    });

    it('items should exist after getting the response from the server', function () {
        //THIS LINE IS ALSO VERY IMPORTANT, IT EMULATES THE RESPONSE FROM THE SERVER
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(scope.items).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: In your second test, it should be expect(scope.items).toBeDefined();

Comment: @AbhishekJain sure, I just changed it. But why? The old code was 100% equivalent: `expect(scope.items).not.toBeUndefined()` is the same as `expect(scope.items).toBeDefined()`

Comment: Ahh my bad! Didn't knew that, my apologies!!

Comment: @AbhishekJain no worries, no need to apologize. I initially did `expect(scope.items).not.toBeUndefined()` because in the first call I was doing `expect(scope.items).toBeUndefined()` and I thought that it was going to be more obvious to see the difference. But it's the same. ;)

Comment: I have always used .toBeDefined and .not.toBeDefined in my tests, and never knew that the variant existed. As you said, both are same, using one or the other is just a matter of personal choice. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The question title states this is to test a service, but the code of the question looks like an attempt is being made to test the controller. This answer describes how to test the controller.

---

If you're testing the controller that calls `httpServices.getItems`, then you need to mock it/stub `getItems` in order to

- Control it on the test
- Not assume any behaviour of the real `httpServices.getItems`. After all, you're testing the controller, and not the service.

A way to do this is in a `beforeEach` block (called before the controller is created) provide a fake implementation of `getItems` that just saves the callback passed to it.

```
var callback;
beforeEach(inject(function(httpServices) {
  callback = null;
  spyOn(httpServices, 'getItems').and.callFake(function(_callback_) {
    callback = _callback_;
  });
});
```

In the test you can then call this callback, passing in some fake data, and test that this has been set properly on the scope.

```
it('saves the items passed to the callback on the scope', function () {
  var testItems = {};
  callback(testItems);
  expect($scope.items).toBe(testItems);
});
```

This can be seen working at http://plnkr.co/edit/Z7N6pZjCS9ojs9PZFD04?p=preview

---

If you do want to test `httpServices.getItems` itself, then separate tests  are the place for that. Assuming `getItems` calls `$http`, then you are most likely to need to use `$httpBackend` to handle mock responses. Most likely, these tests would not instantiate any controller, and I suspect not need to do anything on any scope.